# OROCommerce Customer email templates styling

Tags: orocrm, orocommerce

I am having some trouble setting up the templates for the emails in OROCommerce .
I am looking at the style guide that is available here: https://doc.oroinc.com/frontend/storefront-design/storefront-style-guide/quick-start/ and I am seeing that the emails have a nice formatted header, footer and styling, but all the emails that are sent from a fresh OROCommerce install are missing the header, footer and email styles.

I'we already created some configuration in order to allow the admin user to setup the email template from System Configuration and extened \Oro\Bundle\EmailBundle\Manager\EmailTemplateManager::sendTemplateEmail, but I think that there should be an easier way to add styling to the OROCommerce Customer emails.

Can you tell me if I am missing something or if this templates will be available in the near future or do I have to edit each email template to include the header, footer and styling ?

Answer (score 1):

> EmailTemplateManager::sendTemplateEmail

It's a good solution, as there is no way to provide a common template for all the emails out of the box.

> Do I have to edit each email template to include the header, footer and styling

It's one of the options, also includes are disabled by default in the email twig sandbox, you'll have to enable it to start using.

You can update many templates at once using the data migration, as all the templates are stored in the database.